# basic blue prism email login object

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Trying to learn basic blue prism.
I have made an object to login to my gmail account.

It enters the page where mail id has to be entered. The email id gets entered and the next page appears where the password has to be entered. But in the writer tool it shows the following message : "**Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Write Stage 'Writer2' on page 'Initialise' - No elements match the supplied query terms**"

I looked into all the most obvious bugs and I cant find anything wrong. Can someone please give any suggestions as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Please specify the obvious checks that you have made. Then, you might get a more accurate answer. Also, please include a screenshot of the attribute list in your application modeller.

Answer (score 1):

The specific error message you're getting indicates there's an issue with your spying of the element you're attempting a Write on.

Without knowing anything else about the way you've included/excluded certain attributes of the element you're attempting to write to, the only sound advice one could offer would be to open the Application Modeler and trial-and-error the "Match?" for each attribute until you're able to use the "Highlight" button and verify a single interface element is selected. (Usually in circumstances such as yours, the "Value" attribute of the element you've spied has its Match checkbox selected, but the value has changed since spying it, thus making it not a match.)

Answer (score 0):

check if the data item you are storing the password in is of password type.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password by going ahead with the "write" property and delete once and drag-drop again at the same place and click OK. reset the flowchart and run them again, you'll not get the error. I had faced the same issue earlier and got fixed.
It sometimes happens due to the slowness of your internet connection BP not able to read the data item info and directly moved to next steps, to fix it, you can use wait functionality and give the 8-10 sec of wait time. 
Hope this helps.
stay blessed!

Answer (score -1):

When spying a browser please make sure you are using HTML mode to capture the necessary Element (please note that BP only supports IE, so no Chrome or other browser!). Also, please remember that the browser page you are spying has to be launched from the Application Modeller in order to be "attached" by BP.
To cycle between modes, simply hit the Alt key after clicking "Identify" on the Application Modeller.  After you have captured the correct area of the page where your password goes, uncheck all the attributes of the element that are blank and also the URL attribute (you should be left with 4 maybe 5 atributes left), then hit "Apply" and "OK". Click "Highlight" to make sure BP still finds the element of the page that you want. Then in your Process or Object canvas, use a "Write" stage and drop this element you just created in the Element field, and the password into the Value field (the value has to be between "" unless you are using a data item instead of typing it in). If you have done all this, the "Write" stage should most definitely enter the password into the password field. Good luck!